# Inline Background Image for Text

Tags: css

I want to use a **background image** to highlight text in a paragraph. I do not want to use the background-color property for this as I want an image that look more like it was hand highlighted. How can I do this INLINE? I seem to only be able to do it as a block element and then the text breaks to its own line. I need it inline, a sentence here or there within a paragraph.

Example of it working but only as a block level element:
[link text](https://www.careersinmusic.com/production-music-looperman.aspx)

Please scroll down a bit to the YELLOW highlighted text. I need the highlighting to NOT cause the text to break onto the next line AND to end when the associated span ends, which could be right in the middle of a paragraph.

THANK YOU! I read all over the place and could not see a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What browser are you using?  Works fine in Firefox 3.6.10 with `display: inline`.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! I tried it before but it did not preview in Dreamweaver. It still doesn't which makes editing hard. Ideas BESIDES using something other than Dreamweaver?

Answer (score 1):

Change `display: block` to `display: inline` on `.highlite1`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the span to display:inline seems to work in Chrome and FF. Not tried it in others though.